# Dividing by Zero - Unexpected Result

Tags: bugs, numerics, evaluation, splines

When I divide this number by zero I get this for an answer.

```
ans = 2345900/0
```

(* [image] *)

What is surprising is that in taking the square root, Mathematica seems to map the entire universe to some town called New Cuyama...

```
Sqrt@ans
```

(* [image] *)

Not sure if bug, feature, or fundamental truth.

**EDIT**

I'm afraid to show the result of `42/0`. If someone else is brave enough...

Comment: @user6014 Let's wait until tomorrow...

Comment: (+1) Well, as [Gamow](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_Gamow) might have put it, if this is true maybe it's time to drop _Mathematica_ and take up Divinity.

Comment: You were not supposed to know about this number. Now it will be replaced by another number. (Some say this has happened several times before)

Comment: Please don't evaluate `137/0`, a finely structured error hangs your PC at the speed of light.

Comment: Happy 42. birthday. Hope the party was fine. Tomorrow the one in the denominator will appear. Good night.

Comment: I dunno about the rest of you, but I actually tried to evaluate it...

Comment: I am disappointed no one else has linked to this, http://www.infinitecat.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is getting me anxious.